# A tough Word-Nurikabe puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

I came up with this Word Nurikabe Puzzle, which was NOT a part of the [Puzzle Ramayan](https://logicmastersindia.com/live/?contest=PR202106), the qualifiers for [Indian Puzzle Championship](https://logicmastersindia.com/PR/2021pr.asp).

---

### [image: Tougher puzzle.]

**Rules**

- Place  the  given  words  in  the  grids  ‘islands’,  so  that  the  words  are  readable  in orthogonally (horizontally and vertically) connected cells.
- It may be possible to trace the word in multiple ways within an
  island but there must be at least one way to do so.
- Different words can't touch each other orthogonally (horizontally and vertically).
- The remaining  cells  must form a  single  connected  shape and
  can't  have  any  2x2  areas anywhere.
- Each word has exactly one
  letter given in the grid.

---

Given example :

[image: Word Nurikabe example]

---

Solution for the above :

[image: Solution to the given example of word nurikabe]

---

To solve online on penpa, click [this link](https://git.io/JCqaS)

Comment: When reading a word, must each character be used only once? For example, in QUARANTINE, must there be two cells with A's, or can the same cell be traced twice?

Comment: There should be two different cells reading A.

Comment: Ok need to agree with this, the solution is not unique. Maybe you are missing some deduction?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, as the puzzle had multiple solutions it was dropped off from the competition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution is not unique.

> The word placements can easily be found:
>  X is COVAXIN, so V must be VACCINATION
>  L is SOLITUDE, so D must be SYNDEMIC
>  Then M is CONTAINMENT, so C is PRECAUTIONS
>  And finally, I is QUARANTINE
>
>  Here, I just threw the top three words in as they appear, and worked out multiple solutions for the bottom half of the grid without much logic. I expect that there are many more solutions with quite a bit of variety.
>
>  [image: Multiple solutions]

Comment: Your solutions are correct and yes, since the puzzle had multiple solutions it was dropped off from the competiton.